# Контроллер в .NET api при получении POST запроса заполняет моделью пустыми значениями вместо тех что в теле запроса

Tags: asp.net-web-api

То что передаю(TS Angular):

```
export class User{
  public name:string;
  public age: number;

  constructor(name: string, age: number){
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }
```

Запрос

```
return this.httpClient.post('https://localhost:44471/api/Cut/Cut', new User("Я тупой)", 100))
```

Тело запроса(смотрю в отладчике браузера):

```
{"name":"Я тупой)","age":100}
```

Контроллер на backend-е:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class CutController : ControllerBase
{
  [HttpPost]
  [Route("[action]")]
  public IActionResult Cut([FromBody]User user)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("557");
    Console.WriteLine(user.name);
    Console.WriteLine(user.age);
    user.Age += 10;
    Console.WriteLine(user.age);
    return Ok();
  }
```

То что выплевывает контроллер в консоль:

```
557

0
10
```

В отладчике в полях user.name: null, user.age: 0.
Соответственно вопрос, куда делись данные?

Answer (score 0):

Как оказалось поля модели должны быть свойствами, мне это помогло. Если поля не определены как свойства, то десериализация все равно "работает", но поля заполняются дефолтными значениями типов.

```
namespace ProfCut.Models
{
    public class User
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public double age { get; set; }

    }
}
```